# Create a new structure inside a class public method

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, structure

Hello I am trying to create a new structure inside my class but i think there is an issue with public and private scope of some sort.

```
typedef struct Currency
{
Currency(Coin *coin, Currency *next, int _position) : _coin(coin), _next(next),  _position(0) {}
Currency() : _next(NULL), _position(0) {}
Coin *_coin;
Currency *_next;
int _position;
};
```

that is my structure that is inside my public section of my class
 and when I try to do this

```
if(location <= exit)
{
start = location + 11;
begin = response.find("label", start);
end = begin - start - 3;
findStrings(start, end, s, &response);
curr._next = new Currency();
}
```

it says Expected type specifier for the new Currency() call.
is there something i am missing or should structures not be used this way?

class Exchange
{
    public:

```
    typedef struct Badge
    {
        Badge(std::string id, Badge next, Badge prev, int length) : _id(id), _next(&next), _prev(&prev), _position(length) {}
        Badge() : _id(""), _next(NULL), _prev(NULL), _position(0) {}
        std::string _id;
        Badge *_next;
        Badge *_prev;
        int _position;
    };


    typedef struct Currency
    {
        Currency(Coin *coin, Currency *next, int _position) : _coin(coin), _next(next), _position(0) {}
        Currency() : _next(NULL), _position(0) {}
        Coin *_coin;
        Currency *_next;
        int _position;
    };

    /* constructor and destructor */
    Exchange();
    Exchange(std::string str);
    ~Exchange();

    /* Assignment operator */
    Exchange& operator =(const Exchange& copyExchange);
    void parseTradePairs(Currency curr, const std::string response, int begin, int exit);

private:        
    std::string _exch;
    Currency *_currencies;
    Badge *_ident;
```

};

## endif

^ that is in the class header

```
Exchange::Exchange()
{
    _exch = "";
}
Exchange::Exchange(std::string str)
{
    _exch = str;
    _ident = new Badge;
    _currencies = new Currency;

    std::string pair;
    std::string response;
    CURL *curl;

    getTradePairs(curl, response);
    int exit = response.find_last_of("marketid");
    parseTradePairs(*_currencies, response, 0, exit);

}
void parseTradePairs(Exchange::Currency curr, std::string response, int begin, int exit)
{
     int start;
     int end;
     string s;
     int location = response.find("marketid", begin);
    if(location <= exit)
    {
        start = location + 11;
        begin = response.find("label", start);
        end = begin - start - 3;
        findStrings(start, end, s, &response);
        curr._next = new Currency();
    }

}
```

^that is in the class cpp obviously.

Comment: Could you show it in your class declaration context please. Especially those problems you're mentioning are hard to tell without seeing that.

Comment: edited sorry there you go. let me know if you have mroe questions

Comment: If your using code is outside the class, change type to `Exchange::Currency`, that should do the trick.

Comment: @JayBell please see the preview and fix formatting before submitting edits! Somebody fixed the first version of your question, see that for how to do the same in the added part too.

Comment: Thank you for the fix and ya I did the four space indenting not sure why it didnt show up like that! Next time ill make sure it is working by trying the CTRL+K as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function definition in the .cpp isn't related to the `Exchange` class. You'll need to write:

```
void Exchange::parseTradePairs
         (Exchange::Currency curr, std::string response, int begin, int exit)
{
    // ...
}
```

Also: Anywhere outside your class scope you'll need to use `Exchange::Currency` to access the type.

Answer (score 1):

If you're instantiating `Currency` within a method of the class, then this should work fine.
But if you're instantiating `Currency` elsewhere, you'll need to scope it with the class' name.

I.e. `ClassName::Currency`

Of course `Currency` needs to be visible in the scope that you do that, and making it `public` should take care of that.

Comment: Nope! This is not the primary problem.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: This not an answer to edited question, downvote to request deletion... :-)

One issue is this:

```
typedef struct Currency {
};
```

It compiles, but C++ compiler should say something like `warning: 'typedef' was ignored in this declaration` (and if it does not, enable warning!). You should use one of these:

```
struct Currency {
}; // type 'struct Currency' With implicit typedef in C++
```

which in C++ is essentially same as:

```
typedef struct Currency {
} Currency; // explicit typedef
```

or

```
typedef struct {
} Currency; // anonumous struct With typedef type name
```

It is generally best to use the first form in C++. There may be subtle differences in some corner cases, so keep things simple.

C does not do the implicit typedef, so 2nd or 3rd form are sometimes used to avoid needing to use *struct* keyword everywhere. This is good to know because many libraries have same *.h* files for both C and C++.

Comment: Nope! This is not the primary problem.

Comment: @g-makulik yep, wrote this before edit... Can't test right now, does the typedef without a new type name compile?

Comment: I'd guess so, at least for c compliance it should.

Comment: @g-makulik Yep, `gcc` just gives a warning.